# Linear combination of the Slices in a 3D

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, vectorization

I have a 3D matrix sized (x,y,N) and a 2D matrix sized (N,N).

I would like to manipulate the two in a way that each column in the 2D matrix has the coefficients for a linear combination of the 2D sized- (x, y) slices in the 3D matrix. And I would like to do this for all N columns in the 2D matrix.

Schematically,

[image: Schematic Picture Link]

Currently the code looks like:

```
A = zeros(numel(x_axis), numel(y_axis), N);
B = zeros(numel(x_axis), numel(y_axis), N);
C = zeros(N, N)
for i = 1 : N
    for j = 1 : N
        A(:,:,i) = A(:,:,i) + B(:,:,j) * C(j,i);
    end
end
```

But it is quite slow. Is there any way to speed up the MATLAB code by vectorizing?

Comment: Did you have matlab 2016b or later ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have access to 2015a through 2016a.

Comment: Ok, because matlab 2016b introduce a new feature called implicit expansion which is able to linearize this kind of problem. So the best you can do is to use `bsxfun` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem well, then this should work:

```
[p,q,N] = size(B);
A = reshape( reshape(B, [p*q, N]) * C, [p, q, N]);
```

**edit**: Cleaner version suggested by Suever:

```
A = reshape(reshape(B, [], size(B, 3)) * C, size(B))
```

Generalization to the R-D case:

```
A = reshape(reshape(B, [], size(B, ndims(B))) * C, size(B))
```

Comment: I would probably just do: `A = reshape(reshape(B, [], size(B, 3)) * C, size(B))`

Comment: Good point. I keep forgettting that you can skip arguments in reshape. Yours looks much more elegant for sure. +1 for that.

Comment: How could I possibly extend this to where B is a 4D matrix and where C is still a 2D matrix? In this case I would like to find linear combinations of the 3D slices of B.

Comment: The idea works in an arbitrary number of dimensions. I've made an edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bsxfun` which will calculate this very quickly for you. We have to use `permute` to re-arrange `C` a little bit to ensure that it has conformant dimensions for using `bsxfun` and then we perform the summation along the third dimension of the resulting output and apply `squeeze` to remove the singleton third dimension.

```
A = squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@times, B, permute(C, [3 4 1 2])), 3))
```